# Responsive website design element scaling

Tags: html, css

Well I'm pretty new to responsive design so please forgive me if I ask stupid questions.

So I was creating a website for myself in Dreamweaver. The desktop version of my site looks okay but whenever I open it using my phone or my tablet, the elements do not scale properly.

I've used Media Queries and the site looks okay in Responsive Design mode of Firefox, but in actual devices they do not.

**This is my index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Home</title>

<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400|Raleway:300,400,500|Roboto:100,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="intro">

    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">

        <div class="heading">

            Hi

        </div>

        <div class="para">

            Here goes a brief description about myself and what I do.

        </div>

        <div class="knowMe">

            <input class="button" type="button" name="getToKnowMe" value="Get to know me"/>

        </div>

        <div class="start">
        <a href="#">
            or contact me
        </a>
        </div>

    </div> <!--col-xs-->

    </div> <!--intro-->

</div> <!--container fluid-->

</body>

</html>
```

**And this is my main.css:**

```
*{
    font-family: roboto;
}

a, a:hover, a:link, a:active, a:visited{
  color: white !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

html{
    font-size: 16px;
}

.container-fluid{
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.intro{
    background: linear-gradient(#E93D1D,#E95236);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    padding: 5em;
    height: 48em;
}

.intro .heading{
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    font-size: 8em;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro .para{
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro .start{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: white;
    text-decoration-style: dotted;
}

.intro .button{
  box-sizing: content-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1em 2.5em;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  text-overflow: clip;
  margin: 3em 2em 0.75em 2em;
  background: none;
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}

.intro .button:hover{
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;   
  background: white;
  color: #E95236;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){

    .intro{
        padding: 1em;
        height: 41em;
    }

    .intro .heading{
        font-size: 5em;
        padding-top: 1em;
    }

    .intro .para{
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .intro .button{
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: 0.8em 0.8em;
    }

    .intro .start{
        font-size: 1em;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:375px){

    .intro{
        padding: 1em;
        height: 48em;
    }

    .intro .heading{
        font-size: 8em;
        padding-top: 0.65em;
    }

    .intro .para{
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    .intro .button{
        font-size: 1.5em;
        padding: 0.75em 0.75em;
    }

    .intro .start{
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width:414px){

    .intro{
        padding: 1em;
        height: 53em;
    }


    .intro .heading{
        font-size: 8em;
        padding-top: 1em;
    }

    .intro .para{
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    .intro .button{
        font-size: 1.5em;
        padding: 0.75em 1.2em;
    }

    .intro .start{
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

}
```

**This is how my website looks in Firefox Responsive Design Mode:**

https://image.ibb.co/jCr54k/moz.jpg

**This is how it looks in my iPhone SE:**

https://image.ibb.co/ihA4x5/IMG_1675.png

It'd be great if someone could just tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this class

```
html,body{
width:100%;
height:100vh;
/* or just add*/
background-color: #e94224;
/* and no need to use those classes */
}
.container-fluid {
padding: 0 !important;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
.intro {
 /* change the height from 48em to 100% */
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Okay let me try it.

Comment: Nope it's the same. Nothing's changed :(

Comment: did you reload you page with cash !?

Comment: yes. I've even tried adding !important, but it doesn't work.

Comment: now it is ok, i tested it :), try adding those classes

Comment: Yes, it actually works. Can you please tell me how do I increase the font sizes in the mobile site?

Comment: you handle that by adding media query  [see this](http://www.stephanimoroni.com/css3-media-queries-affect-on-font-sizes/)
if i answred your question please mark it as answred.

Comment: I'll check out you link. I've added  Media Queries but the font size seems too small in the mobile site. But whatever. Thanks man. You're a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

It all seems fine to me, with the exception of `body` not having any height.

try adding css:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**UPDATE**: Never mind, this won't be enough. You've got some heights set in other places.

Comment: Okay let me try it. I'll let you know.

Comment: No problem. It's enough for me that you tried to help me out. Thanks :)